# Struggling with the JQuery/Bootstrap version of Joomla's Modal Window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla3.0

I've been trying to get a JQuery version of a modal window working within the Joomla framework.

This works to get the mootools version to pop up an iframe...

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.mootools'); ?>
<a href="http://www.example.com/page2.html" class="modal" 
   rel="{handler:'iframe'}">
   Click here to launch a popup</a>
```

However, it would be nice not to have to use two javascript libraries, so I ideally want to get a jQuery equivalent working.  I have added...

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.ui');
```

I get the impression it needs the bootstrap framework too, but that is something I'm not overly familiar with.

What I'm really after is a JQuery equivalent of my Mootools example, or an explination of what is the best-practise way of doing this when using the JQuery framework in your Joomla template.

(NB I want only to use the core Joomla approach - I know how to add my own modal script outside of that)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for bootstrap modal window in Joomla 3.You can try below code-

```
$name = "myModal";
$html = '<a href="#modal-' . $name.'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">Launch modal</a>';
$params = array();
$params['title']  = "test";
$params['url']    = "http://localhost/";
$params['height'] = 400;
$params['width']  = "100%";
echo $html .= JHtml::_('bootstrap.renderModal', 'modal-' . $name, $params);
```